# How can i learn Table Name in database an column name?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio

How can i learn table Name in database an how can i learn any Table's Column name?

```
SELECT Col.COLUMN_NAME, Col.DATA_TYPE

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS Col

       LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS Usg ON Col.TABLE_NAME = Usg.TABLE_NAME AND Col.COLUMN_NAME = Usg.COLUMN_NAME

       LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS Con ON Usg.CONSTRAINT_NAME = Con.CONSTRAINT_NAME

WHERE Col.TABLE_NAME = 'Addresses_Temp' AND Con.Constraint_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

But it returns to me empty data:(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is but here it goes anyway....

**Displays Table information**

```
Select * From Information_Schema.Tables
```

**Displays Column information**

```
Select * From Information_Schema.Columns
```

**Displays Table Constraint information**

```
Select * From Information_Schema.Table_Constraints
```

Here is some further resources relating to the Information Schema views.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

If your query returns no rows then maybe the table doesn't exist anymore.  It is named `_temp` after all

Answer (score 0):

Your query structure must be below

```
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='SchemaName' AND TABLE_NAME='TableName'
```

for example:

```
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND TABLE_NAME='Category'
```